# How does the Hyperref package affect on regular \ref-command to break this code

Tags: macros, hyperref, cross-referencing, packages

I write my thesis in LaTeX and refer to the research questions in subsequent chapters. I label the questions and designed the `\nthref` (se code below) to refer to the nth research question by its label.

My problem is that if my code includes the hyperref-package, which I also like, my `\nthref` code breaks down. It seems like when hyperref is used, `\ref{}` still inserts a number, but then again not really. I can no longer get an `\ifx\ref{#1}=1` statement to trigger even if the `\ref` in question becomes a 1. I'm confused, because in the rendered pdf the 1 looks identical. Shouldn't `\ref{q:whatever}` always replace with the same thing? Confusion!

My question is what hyperref really does to the `\ref`-command in order to break my code in the example below. Removing `\usepackage{hyperref}` of course is a solution, but not one I'd prefer, mostly because I wouldn't understand *why* I'd have to do it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Hyperref destroys \nthref below
\usepackage{hyperref}

% let nthref give an ordinal word for the reference to the label of of an enumeric list environment - like research questions
\newcommand\nthref[1]{\ifcase\ref{#1}???\or{first}\or{second}\or{third}\or{fourth}\or{fifth}\else???\fi}

\begin{document}
There are research questions like:
\begin{enumerate}
\label{sec:questions}
  \item What is a sunset?\label{q:sunset}
  \item Can sunsets be modelled?\label{q:model_sunset}
  \item How many sunsets are there in two pineapples?\label{q:pinaple_relation}
\end{enumerate}
% Research questions are labeled as:
%   q:sunset
%   q:model_sunset
%   q:pinaple_relation

In research question \ref{q:sunset} (the \nthref{q:sunset} research question) sunsets are considered. Sunsets remain the themes of the \nthref{q:model_sunset} and \nthref{q:pinaple_relation} questions.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `hyperref` makes `\ref` unexpandable, that's the reason

Comment: I would expect that the first run of the document should produce errors

Comment: I'm surprised it ever worked.  \ref has always been protected (cannot be expanded until printed).  It depends on how \ifcase is implemented.  OTOH, hyperref turns \ref into a \hyperlink, not just a macro.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am not sure what you mean, `\ref`is not protected and can definitely be expanded, the problem is that it inserts a `\null` token which expands to `\hbox{}` so it can not be used in numerical context as is.

Comment: (independently of the fact that `\thesection` etc... do not alway produce numerical things to start with, which is what `\label` will store)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\hyperref` version of `\ref` is not expandable, i.e. it can't be used in a `\ifcase` etc. test. directly in order to make a query on its value.

`\hyperref`'s `\ref` command is a protected version and also provides a `\ref*` in order to omit hyperlinks.

However, `\getrefnumber` which is a macro from `refcount` package (which is included by `hyperref` anyway) can be used instead. If a reference is not found, `-1` is returned.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Hyperref destroys \nthref below
\usepackage{hyperref}

% let nthref give an ordinal word for the reference to the label of of an enumeric list environment - like research questions
\newcommand\nthref[1]{\ifcase\getrefnumber{#1}???\or{first}\or{second}\or{third}\or{fourth}\or{fifth}\else???\fi}

\begin{document}

There are research questions like:
\begin{enumerate}
\label{sec:questions}
  \item What is a sunset?\label{q:sunset}
  \item Can sunsets be modelled?\label{q:model_sunset}
  \item How many sunsets are there in two pineapples?\label{q:pinaple_relation}
\end{enumerate}
% Research questions are labeled as:
%   q:sunset
%   q:model_sunset
%   q:pinaple_relation

In research question \ref{q:sunset} (the \nthref{q:sunset} research question) sunsets are considered. Sunsets remain the themes of the \nthref{q:model_sunset} and \nthref{q:pinaple_relation} questions.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ref` has never been expandable, independently of hyperref. `\edef\x{\ref{sec:1}}` then `\show\x` produces `1\hbox {}` when reference is defined. So it can not be used in `\ifcase` as is and this is not `hyperref`'s fault.

Comment: @jfbu: As far as I know, `\ref` is made expandable with `calc` package. I know that the regular version isn't expandable

Comment: It does not change anything to my `\edef\x{\ref{sec:1}}` test. There is of course the extra problem that this produces the resulte of `\thesection` etc or `\thepage` for `\pageref` which is not guaranteed to be usable in numerical contexts anyhow, but here the problem is with the extra `\null` token. Of course in case reference is undefined then LaTeX code is even less compatible with `\ifcase` etc...

Comment: As long as `\theenumi` expands to an integer number, `\getrefnumber` is correct here. I did not claim that `\ifcase\ref{...}` is useful.

Comment: when I said in my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392713/how-does-the-hyperref-package-affect-on-regular-ref-command-to-break-this-code#comment975832_392718) "has never been expandable" my tongue slipped I meant "not compatible with numerical contexts". This is all caused by an extra `\null` thing. I think  your advice is very good about using `\getrefnumber`, I just wanted to point out that it is not `hyperref`'s fault if one can not use `\ref` in numerical contexts.

Comment: Not hyperref's fault then. Great. I'm not very proud of writing my own `\ifcase` for this anyways, but `\getrefnumber` should have been the way to go anyway, with or without hyperref - and I prefer _with_. Thank you very much guys!

Comment: @JosefLilljegren I see now that you don't necessarily need "numerical only context" so the `\hbox{}` was not bothering you. Surely `hyperref̀` indeed made matters worse, but you already had this extra, benign for you `\hbox{}`. Be careful with `\ifcase` if using `\getrefnumber` perhaps you need toe xplicitely leave a space token so that TeX does not expand too far looking for a number.